# How can I check if the brackets in a string is balanced?

Tags: python-3.x, class, stack

I need to check if a string have balanced brackets using stack but one of my test case is wrong as the brackets is not even but it's returning True.

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    def is_empty(self):
        if len(self.list) == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def push(self, item):
        self.list.append(item)
    def pop(self):
        return self.list.pop()
    def peek(self):
        return self.list[-1]

def balanced_brackets(text):
    s = Stack()
    opening = '(<'
    closing = ')>'
    mapping = dict(zip(opening, closing))

    for letter in text:
        if letter in opening:
            s.push(mapping[letter])
        elif letter in closing:
            if not s or letter != s.pop():
                return False
    return True
```

'''

```
print(balanced_brackets('(<x>)(())()'))#this test case is correct
print(balanced_brackets('(((((((xyz))))))'))#but this is wrong
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must check your stack at the end of the `for` loop:

```
def balanced_brackets(text):
    s = Stack()
    opening = '(<'
    closing = ')>'
    mapping = dict(zip(opening, closing))

    for letter in text:
        if letter in opening:
            s.push(mapping[letter])
        elif letter in closing:
            if s.is_empty() or letter != s.pop():
                return False
    if not s.is_empty():
        return False
    return True
```

**output**:

```
print(balanced_brackets('(<x>)(())()'))
print(balanced_brackets('(((((((xyz))))))'))

True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `collections.Counter` object to just count the amount of brackets present and compare those numbers to determine balance:

```
from collections import Counter

cnt = Counter('(((((((xyz))))))')
if cnt['('] != cnt[')']:
    print('unbalanced')
```

I think you get the idea and can build on it.

Comment: But it's there a way that will involve stack?

Comment: What about `s = ')('`?!

Comment: Yes you could check which of the two braces has more/less counts and push it to the stack accordingly.